# Set minimum step size in chart js

Tags: graph, chart.js

I am using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) 2.0 version to draw graphs, i want to define **minimum step size** in bar graph

```
var myNewChart = new Chart(grapharea, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,                        
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [
                            {
                                ticks: {
                                    min: 0, // it is for ignoring negative step.
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    stepSize: 1  // if i use this it always set it '1', which look very awkward if it have high value  e.g. '100'.
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });
```

this time i am using

> stepSize: 1

i am using this step size to **ignore the point value e.g. '0.5'**, it shows when the max graph values id less e.g '2'.
if i use this it always set the step it '1', which look very awkward if it have high value  e.g. '100'.

> I am looking for such thing:
> suggestedMin = 1

Is there any thing to define thie minimum step size which should not be fixed in higher value cases.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you don't want to show point value (e.g. 0.5) labels you could write a callback function to filter the point value labels instead of using stepSize.

Like this:

```
ticks: {
    min: 0, // it is for ignoring negative step.
    beginAtZero: true,
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
        if (Math.floor(value) === value) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ma7h611L/

### **Update:**

As noted by [Atta H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192359/atta-h) and [Lekoaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5268771/lekoaf) below, Chart.js added the precision property to ticks. It is available since version 2.7.3. See Lekoaf's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863118/1695088) how to use this.

Comment: Just tried this on my chart. It works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: i tried precision: 0 and it worked for me
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html

Comment: Precision: 0 worked equally well as the callback function and is much cleaner.

Comment: The precision property is new since version 2.7.3 and is indeed much cleaner. I will also update this answer and add this information.

Comment: can you find any documentation for the option `callback`? I could not find it from the Chartjs documentation page, looks like it's a hidden feature?

Comment: @Hopeless this might be what you are looking for: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html?h=callback

Comment: @Daantie thank you, it's strange that the option is not officially documented (like others) but put in a sample about customizing the ticks. Really strange.

Answer (score 37):

```
ticks: {
    precision: 0
}
```

This worked equally well as the callback function above and is much cleaner.

> precision, if defined and stepSize is not specified, the step size will be rounded to this many decimal places.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html